# Make Spring Boot /actuator/heath run checks in parallel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have several custom checks for my /actuator/health check. Some of these call other services to see if they are reachable. Unfortunately this can take some time. Therefore I'd like spring boot to make these checks in parallel.

Demo:

```java
@Component
public class HealthCheck1 extends AbstractHealthIndicator {
    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // actually make a service call
        builder.up();
    }
}

@Component
public class HealthCheck2 extends AbstractHealthIndicator {
    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // actually make a service call
        builder.up();
    }
}
```

```
$ time http localhost:8080/actuator/health
HTTP/1.1 200 
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
Date: Fri, 03 Jan 2020 14:54:31 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
    "components": {
        "diskSpace": {
            "details": {
                "free": 398020632576,
                "threshold": 10485760,
                "total": 499963174912
            },
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "healthCheck1": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "healthCheck2": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "ping": {
            "status": "UP"
        }
    },
    "status": "UP"
}


real    0m10.359s
user    0m0.242s
sys 0m0.036s
```

This shows that the checks are currently made sequentially. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: There is an open issue for Spring Boot to support parallel execution of composite health indicators: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2652

Answer (score 2):

Since currently its not really possible to run all health checks in parallel as @Roland Weisleder has pointed in comments, you can do the following workaround:

Instead of doing the actual check in `HealthCheck1`:

1. create another bean that makes the long check
2. Run it in some thread periodically (with @Scheduled, Scheduled Executor or whatever)
3. Make it store a decision locally in a field, there is no multi-threaded access here, that bean is a singleton so you should be good to go.
4. Inject that bean into the HealthCheck and get the state.

```
@Component
public class MyCustomBeanCheck {
   private boolean isOk;

   // run periodically
   public void doCheck() {
       isOk = contactServiceTakesALongTime();
   }

   public boolean isOk() {
      return isOk;
   }
}

public class HealthCheck1 extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    private MyCustomBeanCheck myCustomBeanCheck;

    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws InterruptedException {
       if(myCustomBeanCheck.isOk()) { // immediate access
         builder.up();
       } else {
         builder.down();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another workaround:

```java
@RestController
public class SystemCheckBoundary {

    private static final int TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 10;

    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class CheckResult {
        HealthIndicator check;
        CompletableFuture<MyHealth> futureHealth;

        public String getCheckName() {
            String name = check.getClass().getSimpleName();
            if (name.endsWith("HealthIndicator")) {
                name = name.substring(0, name.length() - "HealthIndicator".length());
            }
            return Character.toLowerCase(name.charAt(0)) + name.substring(1);
        }

        public MyHealth getHealth() {
            try {
                return futureHealth.get(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                return new StaticHealth(DOWN);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                return new StaticHealth(DOWN);
            }
        }
    }

    @JsonInclude(NON_EMPTY)
    private interface MyHealth {
        @JsonUnwrapped
        Status getStatus();

        Map<String, Object> getDetails();
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class DelegatingHealth implements MyHealth {
        private Health health;

        @Override
        public Status getStatus() {
            return health.getStatus();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getDetails() {
            return health.getDetails();
        }
    }

    @Getter
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    private static class StaticHealth implements MyHealth {
        @NonNull
        private Status status;
        private Map<String, Object> details;
    }

    @Value
    private static class SystemHealth {
        Map<String, MyHealth> components;

        public String getStatus() {
            return components.values().stream()
                    .map(MyHealth::getStatus)
                    .reduce(UP, this::min)
                    .getCode();
        }

        private Status min(Status a, Status b) {
            List<Status> statuses = asList(DOWN, UP, UNKNOWN);
            return statuses.indexOf(a) < statuses.indexOf(b) ? a : b;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private List<HealthIndicator> checks;

    @Resource
    private TaskExecutor executor;

    @GetMapping("/myactuator/health")
    public SystemHealth check() {
        return new SystemHealth(checks.stream()
                .map(this::getHealth)
                .collect(toList()).stream() // terminate stream so checks are running in parallel; don't call get() to early
                .collect(toMap(CheckResult::getCheckName, CheckResult::getHealth)));
    }

    private CheckResult getHealth(HealthIndicator healthIndicator) {
        return new CheckResult(healthIndicator, supplyAsync(() ->
                new DelegatingHealth(healthIndicator.getHealth(true)), executor));
    }

}
```

Note that this won't be part of actuator but a "normal" RestController.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot >= 2.2, you can use the separate library [spring-boot-async-health-indicator](https://github.com/antoinemeyer/spring-boot-async-health-indicator/) to make your healthchecks run in parallel (and asynchronously) by simply annotating them with `@AsyncHealth`.

Example:

```
@AsyncHealth
@Component
public class HealthCheck1 implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // makes a service call on a different thread than /health
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

*Disclaimer: I created this library for this exact purpose*